# Class AppDelegate has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift

I downloaded sample code from here for a location tracking application https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-05-getting-started-ios-location-tracking-and-streaming-w-swift-programming-language/. I am trying to run the application but in the AppDelegate class I am getting an error saying "Class AppDelegate has no initializers". What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties
    //var window: UIWindow?
    var window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // MARK: - App Life Cycle

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Adding a Navigation Controller and tool bar
        self.window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil))

        // Make window visible
        self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that actually all of the code you have for `AppDelegate`? Are there any other properties besides `window`?

Comment: Yeah that's all that came in the source code.

Comment: Please copy and paste, in the question, the *exact* error the compiler is giving you. Thanks!

Comment: Between your comment, the date in the link, and the function signature, at least one issue may well be the Swift version you are using. Try this: (1) Create a brand new project. (2) Use the AppDelegate.swift file Xcode creates *as is*. (3) Copy/past the *contents* of this *application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)*, retaining the function signature Xcode created.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the window to be an optional value with no default. just as you originally had then commented out

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

then give window a value and programmatically add the root view controller when your app launches

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let viewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

}